# Google oauth2 authorization in iframe/popup

Tags: oauth-2.0, x-frame-options

My application works in iframe (injected with chrome extension).
The application needs to ask user some permissions with google oauth2.
Redirecting to oauth-page does not work directly in iframe, 
because of X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN at https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth

Is there a way to display the page in popup?

Answer (score 1):

[Google+ Sign-in](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/) seems a good choice for your case. It comes with a button that triggers the auth flow in a popup window.