# Google login popup doesn't show on iframe cause the x-frame options sameorigin

Tags: google-app-engine, iframe, google-signin, x-frame-options

Hello to everyone my question is different from the others of the same type:

i have an app developed on google appengine and i want to show this app on a different site of my own in an iframe.

The app need the authentication with google credential before using the app.

If i embed the app into an iframe and the user access to that page, and it is already logged into my app from the direct link, it works correctly.

But if the user enter first my other website with the iframe, and it isn't logged to my app, the google login doesn't show up and he just see a white page, whilte the console show me the error:

> ERROR: Refused to display
>   'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?.....' in a frame because
>   it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

do you know any way to allow the google login to popup into the iframe? there is something i can do about it?

i'm expeting the google login pop up will also show into the iframe, so the user can enter their credential and login to my app and use it correctly.

Comment: Please provide a MVCE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces your issue. This way people do not have to guess what might be the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google oauth2 authorization in iframe/popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10791673/google-oauth2-authorization-in-iframe-popup)

Comment: a duplicate from 2012 doesn't seem it would be valid for a question in 2018, considering the only answer suggests using Google+, which is depreciated.